# ERRO AO SELECIONAR O BANCO DE DADOS

Tags: php

Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in C:\Users\wesle\OneDrive\Imagens\Nova pasta\htdocs\MOBILE\db.php on line 3
FALHA AO SELECIONAR A DATABASE

```
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "") OR DIE("FALHA AO CONECTAR AO SERVIDOR");
$db = mysqli_select_db("sitefitflix", $connect) OR DIE("FALHA AO SELECIONAR A DATABASE");
```

Comment: Documentação [mysqli_select_db()](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.select-db.php)

Answer (score 1):

Veja se ajuda:

```
$sql["host"] = "localhost";
$sql["usuario"] = "seu usuario do banco dados";
$sql["senha"] = "sua senha do banco dados";
$sql["base"] = "nome do seu banco de dados";
$conexao = mysqli_connect($sql["host"],$sql["usuario"],$sql["senha"]);
$select_database = mysqli_select_db($conexao, $sql["base"]);
mysqli_query($conexao, "SET NAMES utf8");
```